# What should I do when migrate in django does not work?

Tags: python, django, migrate, makemigrations

I have a problem with creating models in Django. 
I want to create new model, so I write code:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

In the next step, I did `python manage.py makemigrations` , `python manage.py migrate`. I got this result:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('myfirstapp', '0008_delete_image'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Image',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('image', models.ImageField(upload_to='')),
        ],
    ),
]
```

but I don't have access to Image's table in Django administration.

Does anyone know what should I do? Or can see an error, know of tips, or other ways to help?

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with migrations not working.

Migrations don't make a model appear in the admin. In order to do that, you need to [register your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects).

Comment: I did it and get result:

Comment: Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000024510325AE8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\pierwszawersja\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\X\pierwszawersja\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)

Comment: File "C:\Users\X\pierwszawersja\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\X\pierwszawersja\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\X\pierwszawersja\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\X\pierwszawersja\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 26, in check_admin_app

Comment: errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "C:\Users\X\pierwszawersja\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 81, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'model'